# Automatically refresh dgrid contents

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I am using a dgrid `OnDemandGrid` to display data from a Dojo `JsonRest` store. This works well but I want the grid to automatically display changed data. Implementing a push-based approach where the server tells all clients which data has changed is too much effort, so I am looking for a client-based solution. Using dgrid's `refresh()` is not useful, since this causes flickering and resets the whole grid.

My best guess so far is to periodically fetch all data from a second store instance, compare this to the live store instance and use the `Observable` store wrapper to notify the grid of any changed data.

Is there a better, more elegant solution? If not, how do I do this best?

**edit:** The problem with this approach is to know which rows are currently displayed in the grid. My app works with large amounts of data so syncing the whole set in two dojo stores is not a good idea. Is there a way to tell which rows are currently displayed in the grid? Ideally, the grid would just periodically re-request data for the currently displayed rows. Can't be that hard, right?

**edit2:** My best approach so far is to "hack" the `Observable` store, keeping track of all calls to `observe`. I would then periodically re-execute the observed queries and merge changes into the live store. 
The problem is that dgrid keeps way too many observers open for this to work smoothly. It closes some of them, so there is no error in my code, and I set `farOffRemoval` to 500 (also tried lower and higher).

This is my code so far: https://gist.github.com/3225927

It's nowhere finished but it displays enough debug info to show where the problem is. Since probably nobody wants to set this up and there is no dgrid on jsfiddle, I can tell you that after some scrolling in a 1000 entry grid there are about 10-15 observers and observerStats.abs (count of all rows that are at least observed once) is about 750.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear if you've found a better solution, or if you're stilling using the Observable hack. I'm currently struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Yes I did, see my new answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some CacheStore that you would simply flush (close/destroy) periodically

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store/Cache.html

So basically, you clean the CacheStore, then redo your query.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does neither work (store.Cache does not cache queries, only single items) but it also misses the point of my question.

Comment: Oh well, serves me right for trying to help... Btw got the solution but since i got downvoted meanwhile, i'll keep it for me. Have fun.
And btw, store.Cache does cache queries, if you want to use the cached queries you have to use store.Cache.query() instead of JsonRest.query(). Whatever...

Comment: Come on. No need to be rude. If you have a solution I would be very happy to upvote and accept it. Sadly you were wrong again. store.Cache saves all single items to the cache store (let's call it Memory). If you want to get queries, not single items from the cache you have to use Memory.query instead of Cache.query

Comment: Hey, I was not being rude. About the cache stuff, it's in the doc link i gave you : "Doing get() and query() call results are added to the cache (unless they don’t meet provided criteria), but only get() uses the cache, whereas query() uses the master store. If you want to a query to come from the cache, directly call query() on the caching store." As for the item-level diff... I do not need your upvote.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of thinking, I found a better solution to the problem:
I create a Cache store, which is initially seeded with *all* database records (so this might not scale if you actually have millions of records). This Cache store is wrapped in an Observable store and updated by polling the server for changes (using plain HTTP with a Redis backend, nothing fancy like WebSockets or Comet).

Code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5003727

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I do have millions of records (well, approaching that magnitude at least), but this gave me some ideas at (my data never changes, only grows at one end).